# Language data as as a ratio of the number of words?

Tags: sampling, natural-language, simpsons-paradox

I am analyzing language data (nouns, verbs, etc) of people with and without autism and all of them have different number of words.

Option 1: Would it be best to count each result as a ratio of the number of words:

- P1: Nouns= (20 nouns/100 words)
- P2: Nouns = (50 nouns/250 words)
- P3: Nouns = (10 nouns/105 words)

Option 2: Or count them without the ratios:

- P1: Nouns= 20 nouns
- P2: Nouns = 50 nouns
- P3: Nouns = 10 nouns

Which is better for avoiding a Yule-Simpsons/Simpsons Paradox? Would a test for significance (i.e.. t-test) be useful for choosing one option over another (t-test yields non-significance for difference in number of words so option 2 is used)

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].